# How to change SMTP port number in SSIS mail task

Tags: ssis, smtp, port

need to change SMTP port number from 25 to my mail server SMTP port number.
Is there any way to change the port for SMTP 
Can you suggest any way to run the task

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help: [LINK1](http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.si/2013/08/sending-mail-within-ssis-part-2-script.html) or [LINK2](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxnetcom/thread/a75533eb-131b-4ff3-a3b2-b6df87c25cc8). You will need to use a script task...